# using pagination to load numbers of data

Tags: backbone.js

I want to do pagination in backbone. I have a selectbox and when I click on it I want it to show sepcific number of data.

```
<div class="results right" >
          <form>
            <label for="results">Results pr. page</label>
            <select name="results" id="messageSelect">
              <option value="25" >25</option>
              <option value="50" >50</option>
              <option value="100" >100</option>
              <option value="500" >500</option>
            </select>
          </form>
        </div>
```

This is my collection:

```
pagination : function(perPage, page) {
                page = page - 1;
                var collection = this;
                collection = _(collection.rest(perPage * page));
                collection = _(collection.first(perPage));
                return collection.map( function(model) {
                    return model.toJSON();
                });
            },
```

and this is my view, as you can see when the #messageSelect changes (when the user select numbers) the changedSelect is called, it gets the value that should be shown in each page and calculate the total number of pages. but to be honest I do not know what to do after wards!

```
events : {

                            "change #messageSelect" : "changedSelect",

                        },

       changedSelect : function(e){
        this.selectedMessageId = $("#messageSelect :selected").attr("value");
                console.log("id of select is", this.selectedGroupId);

                var maxPages = Math.ceil(this.collection.messageCount / this.pageSize);
                console.log("max", maxPages);
                var pageToLoad = this.currentMessagePage + 1;
                console.log("load me page", pageToLoad);
```

Before I used pagination, I loaded all the messages by:

```
var messageView = new MessageView({
                                    model : item
                                });
                                this.$el.append(messageView.render().el);
```

but how can I load my message template by using pagination. Can you help me or do you know any relevant example?

Answer (score 0):

There is a Backbone [paginator](https://github.com/backbone-paginator/backbone.paginator) available. I haven't used it myself so I cannot comment on how good it is.